# Why am I getting Heroku error h10 upon successful deploy

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I successfully deployed my MERN app to Heroku but upon going to the site, it says Application Error.

My tail logs this: `Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime` and an error code h10/ status 503.

I'm on a Mac and have repeatedly updated Sass, Node Sass Middleware, NPM, and everything suggested.

bin/www looks like this:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

Is it my package.json? I've tried multiple things there too, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown in a Node.js environment if you forget to set a start script. Heroku uses this script to start your app so if it is missing, it would throw an H10-App crashed error code message.
This can be solved by setting a start script in the package.json. e.g

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

[`dev.to` will let you know in detail about this issue.](https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl#:%7E:text=This%20error%20is%20thrown%20in,App%20crashed%20error%20code%20message.)